# Section title for explaining where a subject fits into a field of study

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrase-requests

A car is a form of transportation.  But so is a bicycle.  When a paper is discussing where a subject (say the car) fits into such a system and contrasting the car with the bicycle what should that section of the paper be called?

In my case the paper deals with computer science and a popular way to implement a design principle.  The section deals with showing that the implementation discussed is not the only implementation that fulfills the principle by briefly introducing another popular though older implementation, contrasting with it and explaining how both can fulfill the design principle.

You can do all the same things in a paper about a car, transportation, and a bicycle.  Just thought they would be a little more accessible examples.

I'm hopping for a word or phrase that makes clear that the section will discuss things other than the subject but only to make clear what the subject is and is not.

If it helps, the section is a subsection to the overview that explains how it works at a high level without getting into examples.

Comment: Not all papers are structured in the same way, so I doubt there is a single definitive answer across all of English. What do comparable papers in your field use? At least, can you provide a more concrete, real-life example?

Comment: @Brian-Hitchcock how's this?

Comment: @choster If I knew how to find papers that did this I could simply look at what their section is titled.  I've peeked out from behind my metaphor.  Does this help?

Comment: It looks as though your question concerns comparing and/or contrasting solutions, rather than putting them into classes or groups. A suggestion for your section title is: 'A comparison of A and B as implementation tools for...' Within the section, you can then highlight the pros and cons of particular features.

Comment: Would taxonomy be inapropreate for this?

Comment: If there is more I should do about the hold please let me know

Comment: Maybe you can add more for clarity. What are other section headings in your paper? Is this a subsection to the introduction or definition of terms?

Comment: @mitch thanks for the feedback.   I've updated the question.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Rereading, this doesn't seem like a queston suited for ELU, but rather academics.SE. It's really about common patterns of writing papers in your subject area. I'd look at other papers in your area that do this. My suspicion is that this is introductory explanatory information or really part of mathematical definitions, doesn't really need its entire own section.

Comment: @Mitch Other papers in my area don't do this that I've noticed.  That's actually something I'd like to change.  To do that though I really need the right word or phrase.

Comment: @CandiedOrange The first section after the introduction is probably called something like 'Definitions', or 'Background' or something like that (sets out the existing details of the subject that you will add to). Make a subsection of that section and call it something like 'Terminology'. Or not. 'Definitions' is more than sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say they are ***[categorizing](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/categorize)*** to see where the car belongs.

> Definition of categorize in English:
>   verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> - Place in a particular class or group:
>     silk is categorized as a luxury import

The next step is to ***[distinguish](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/distinguish)*** what separates the car from the bicycle.

> Definition of distinguish in English:
>   verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1. Recognize or treat (someone or something) as different:
>      the child is perfectly capable of distinguishing reality from fantasy
>
> ...

References:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/categorize
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/distinguish